# VOLTTRON install on rasbian buster

Tags: volttron

Can I get a tip for installing on rasp buster? Im hung up on the install directions to check the status of the `rabbitMQ` server. Traceback of bash console:

```
(volttron) pi@raspberry:~/Desktop/volttron $ echo 'export RABBITMQ_HOME=$HOME/rabbitmq_server/rabbitmq_server-3.7.7'|sudo tee --append ~/.bashrc
export RABBITMQ_HOME=$HOME/rabbitmq_server/rabbitmq_server-3.7.7
(volttron) pi@raspberry:~/Desktop/volttron $ source ~/.bashrc
pi@raspberry:~/Desktop/volttron $ RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmqctl status
bash: RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmqctl: No such file or directory
```

There are a few tracebacks earlier on the installation...

If it makes a difference or not [here is the entire bash console process](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/f32a1e9998edd2ab6fc43b9c3713dca3#file-install-py). The git gist link I just created the name `install.py` even though its just bash commands copied pasted per install directions...

```
`pi@raspberry:~/Desktop $ git clone https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron --branch releases/7.x`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of different issues going on here:

1. The issue you quote above (`RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmqctl: No such file or directory`) is that your shell isn't finding the `rabbitmqctl` command. It looks like you added the `RABBITMQ_HOME` environment variable to your .bashrc, but used the string `RABBITMQ_HOME` instead of the variable expansion `$RABBITMQ_HOME` when you tried to run the command. Try running it as `$RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmqctl status` instead.
2. The `rabbitmqctl status` command will check the status of the rabbitmq application, but I don't think you've done anything to start it yet (that happens when you bootstrap the platform and/or start the platform configured to use the RMQ broker)
3. I think that the traces earlier in the installation process are problematic (appears to be the same error hit two different ways), but you just haven't run into them yet. I haven't seen any issues building gevent on the RPi 4 with buster (though it is pretty slow), but the ctypes error makes me wonder if there's an issue with the underlying c library it is trying to build on top of. I did notice that you're getting amd64 erlang packages, are you running Raspbian on an x86 processor? (if so this isn't a permutation we've tried and you may be hitting some package compatibility edge case we haven't seen)

One thing to try is to manually install cython into your virtualenvironment and then try running the bootstrap script again with the virtualenvironment activated. You could also try and `pip install gevent==20.6.1` directly in that virtualenvironment (this is what the bootstrap script was doing at the failure point). VOLTTRON depends on gevent, so if that isn't installing the platform won't be able to run.

Comment: hello yes im on a x86 laptop converted to rasp buster. I have it already converted to ubuntu... Going to try this route. Thanks for the post

Comment: Hi @Ben L... I am attempting to install VOLTTRON on an old tower. Ubuntu 18.04. When i run thru the VOLTTRON install. I get an error..     `unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1` Is this because this computer is a 32 bit... x86 machine? And VOLTTRON requires a 64 bit for the install?

Comment: Thats with the `python3 bootstrap.py --force` after git cloning the VOLTTRON release/7x

Comment: Actually I am running a 64 bit.. Just checked

Comment: I just made a new SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814384/volttron-install-on-ubuntu-18-04