# VOLTTRON install on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: volttron

Can I get a tip for what I am doing wrong trying to install VOLTTRON on an ubuntu tower?

When I git clone the repo I run into this issue.
`git clone https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron`

I just made a [git gist](https://gist.github.com/bbartling/45e9c9eb28cd87caea18d283fb69e429) since the tracback is too big for stack over flow. Its on the `python3 bootstrap.py` part of the install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may not have installed all of the required system dependencies; see: https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup/VOLTTRON-Prerequisites.html#volttron-prerequisites

You should get the g++ compiler as part of the build-essential package.